# How can I preserve my stem cells?

Tags: stem-cells

I'm considering preserving (banking / cryopreserving) stem cells while young on in off-chance it becomes useful in the future.

I couldn't find any organizations providing this service. Is it because they don't exist or I just missed them?

Ideally I would want to preserve them in Canada, but the United States or other countries might work as well.

I looked on https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/lsg-pdsv.nsf/eng/hn01749.html and searched on Google with various key terms such as "stem cell preservation provider". All I could find are companies that preserve baby's cord blood stem cells.

Answer (score 1):

Further research is necessary as this is only in it's early stages but this should answer all of your questions:

https://www.prescouter.com/2017/04/adult-stem-cell-storage/

Comment: Hi, Medic, welcome to MedSci. Your answer is what's called a link-only answer. The problem is if that link ever breaks, which happens _often_, your answer will become worthless. Since the purpose of stackexchange is to build knowledge bases that will be useful both now and in the future, link-only answers aren't allowed. Please edit your question and add your own text paraphrasing/explaining what the link says. Some quotes from the article supporting your explanation would make it an even better answer. That way, no matter what happens to that link or the article your question remains useful.